# How to play two (or more) audio files simultaneously with just_audio and audio_service?

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio

I tried reading through the project readme and issues on Github to see if it was a possibility to play two or more audio files simultaneously using the `just_audio` and `audio_service` plugins for Flutter. Has anyone achieved something similar using these plugins or similar ones? I currently use these plugins in production so it'd be preferable to stick with them to add the desired functionality to the app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In just_audio, you can create two instances of `AudioPlayer` and set them to play different audio sources. e.g.

```dart
final player1 = AudioPlayer();
final player2 = AudioPlayer();

await player1.setUrl(url1);
await player2.setUrl(url2);
...
player1.play(); // don't await
player2.play(); // don't await
```

If you await each play request, it would not start playing the second one until after waiting for the first one to finish playing. So by *not* awaiting, the second play request should be triggered within milliseconds after the first one, and both will play in parallel.

If for any reason you need to wait until both players have finished playing, you can use `Future.wait`:

```dart
await Future.wait([
  player1.play(),
  player2.play(),
]);
print('done'); // this will print after both players are finished.
```

(Extra example based on your comment) To loop `player2` until `player1` completes:

```dart
await player2.setLoopMode(LoopMode.one);
player2.play(); // don't await
await player1.play(); // wait for player1 to complete
await player1.pause(); // or stop or dispose
await player2.pause(); // or stop or dispose
```

Note that each player uses up native resources, which means two things:

1. You may hit a resource limit if you create too many parallel instances.
2. You should call `dispose` on each player once you're finished using it since this will free up those resources for use by other apps.

On the audio_service side, you are basically implementing callbacks for what you want to happen when the user presses the play button, etc, and you can stick the above code into your callback. For example, if you want to play both players simultaneously when the user clicks "play", you would implement your callback like this:

```dart
Future<void> play() async {
  player1.play();
  player2.play();
}
```

You could also implement the pause callback similarly:

```dart
Future<void> pause() async {
  player1.pause();
  player2.pause();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is out of the scope of my original question and if I'd need to ask a new question, but is there a way to repeatedly loop `player2` until `player1` has finished playing?

Comment: @RyanHeise, Could you please tell me what the limits for parallel instances count? Is it 5 playing sounds at time for most devices or 50 parallel sounds?

Comment: You would have to find that through your own testing, but it may actually vary depending on the resources of the particular device. I'm not sure what those numbers are I'm afraid.

Comment: I've tried this but it can play 2 files in one player instance.  Just a comment.  It can play up to    many files in one instance even if i apply player.stop()  before  playing again. It seems audio player creates duplicate stream in the background. Maybe player.dispose() should clear the data but im not sure if i used it well

Comment: A single player instance can't play two files simultaneously. If it does, it is worth reporting the bug.